# Your App Bundle targets the following unrecognized languages: dpi

Tags: google-play

I got an error saying this while uploading aab file to google play Your App Bundle targets the following unrecognized languages: dpi Please help me

Answer (score 3):

In your app/build.gradle add

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en", "US"
}
```

This is similar to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/614